# InvalidPidMappingException in KafkaListener BeginTransaction

Tags: spring-kafka

We have been getting lots of InvalidPidMappingException failures recently.

I came across https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/660, but this is specific to producerOnly publishing in tx.

In our case, this is happening in consumers, so it cannot be resolved using retries (keeps failing with each rollback retry).

There's a fix in kafka to address this exception, but will probably be released in 4 months (v2.5.0). https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/7115

Is there a way we can recover from these failures?

One option we're considering is to use ContainerAwareErrorHandler to restart the listenercontainer in case of these 2 specific exceptions. Any issues with this approach? what would happen if another listener is processing another message?

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot execute transactional method because we are in an error state
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeFailWithError(TransactionManager.java:924)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginTransaction(TransactionManager.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.beginTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:642)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.beginTransaction(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ProducerFactoryUtils.java:101)
    at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.doBegin(KafkaTransactionManager.java:160)
    at com.projectdrgn.common.messaging.config.KafkaProducerConfig$kafkaTransactionManager$kafkaTransactionManager$1.doBegin(KafkaProducerConfig.kt:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:376)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.recordAfterRollback(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$AddPartitionsToTxnHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:1069)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:307)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id.
```